# How to utilize a block of ipv6 address when making requests

Tags: http, go, ipv6

Hello all: How would I configure http.transport to handle using different ipv6 addresses to issue http requests (makeshift proxies).
What I've tried:

```
    localAddr, err := net.ResolveIPAddr("ip6", "{ipv6 address}")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
localTCPAddr := net.TCPAddr{
    IP: localAddr.IP,
}

webclient := &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
        DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
            LocalAddr: &localTCPAddr,
            Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
            KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
            DualStack: true,
        }).DialContext,
        MaxIdleConns:          100,
        IdleConnTimeout:       90 * time.Second,
        TLSHandshakeTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        ExpectContinueTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
    },
}
```

This fails with with ipv6 addresses:

```
panic: Get https://myip.addr.space/: dial tcp [{localAddr}]:0->[{hostip?}]:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

I have two main questions. How can I:

1. Find the range of available ipv6 addresses I can use
2. Use them programmatically in golang to make http requests (again, mimicking a proxy)

I guess what i'm asking is: how can I replicate this: https://github.com/blechschmidt/freebind/blob/master/freebind.c in go.

Comment: You can't connect to that URL via IPv6 anyway, because the remote server doesn't support IPv6. First, you'll have to use an IPv6-capable IP address service, like my own https://myip.addr.space/

Comment: @MichaelHampton Doing so will still result in a tls handshake timeout. I added this to the post. Thanks for notifying me.